Optimizing JavaScript Code for Better Performance in High-Load Applications
I am developing a high-load web application where performance is critical. I've noticed some lag in the front-end, especially with dynamic content updates.
What I Tried:
Used requestAnimationFrame for animations.
Minimized DOM manipulation.
Debounced event listeners.
function updateContent() {
// Code to dynamically update content
...
}
I expected these optimizations to eliminate the lag, but the performance is still not satisfactory. Are there other techniques or best practices I should consider?
